# How to request user input from the command line (at the same time that you run the script from the command line)

Tags: xcode, powershell, command-line

I have a PowerShell script named Script.ps1. This script has a Read-Host input prompt but I want to make the input BEFORE running the script.

For example:

*C:\User\Desktop\Script.ps1 -input hello*

This is the part of the script that requests the input:

$D = Read-Host -Prompt "Input here"

Comment: `C:\User\Desktop\Script.ps1 -input (Read-Host "Input Here)` ? You should use another parameter name than `input` though since that will result in `$input` in your script. `$input` is a reserved variable.

Comment: Got it, I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script file that prompts the user when parameter binding happens or at the command line.

**Prompting User At Command Line:**

*Script.ps1 Contents:*

```
param(
    [string]$in
)
"the input was $in"
```

*Running the Script:*

```
C:\User\Desktop\Script.ps1 -in (Read-Host "Input Here")
```

*Output:*

```
input here: Hello
the input was Hello
```

---

**Prompting User During Parameter Binding:**

*Script.ps1 Contents:*

```
param(
    [string]$in = (Read-Host "Input Here")
)
"the input was $in"
```

*Executing Script:*

```
C:\User\Desktop\Script.ps1
```

*Output:*

```
Input Here: hello
the input was hello
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!